# i have some encrypted text(data),i don't know what kind of algorithm or what type of encryption used.?

Tags: cryptography, encryption

i have some encrypted text(data),i don't know what kind of algorithm or what type of encryption used.
Is there any software to check all the possibilities to decrypt the text(data) ?

Answer (score 4):

Most encryption algorithms are designed so that it is very difficult to decrypt their products even if you do know what algorithm is used.  To unlock encrypted data you need keys.

The short answer to your question is *no*.  The long answer is a course in cryptography, which would lead you towards the short answer.

Comment: Exactly.  The whole point of good encryption is you can be given both the algorithm and the cipher text (along with other required components like salt) and it will be virtually impossible to decipher before the heat death of the universe.   Simply put even if you **DID** know the algorithm you would have no chance against real encryption.